# listing package dependents

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, rpm, dependencies

I stupidly did "yum remove python" which also ended up removing all the packages that required python as well.

Luckily, I have access to another Linux machine that is a near clone of this machine, and it still has all those packages installed. The catch is that it belongs to someone else and I can, at most, poke around. I also don't know what to specifically re-install on my machine. The list (when I removed python) was humongous.

I was wondering if there were any commands I could enter into this twin machine that could tell me: Of the currently installed packages, which ones depend on python?
I could then use that list to manually re-install each one back on my own machine.
So it's really more of the python dependents, not dependencies.

From looking around, I came across such commands like "repoquery --whatrequires" & "rpm --whatrequires", but these don't seem to generate the same list as "yum remove python".

The 2 machines run RHEL 6.

Comment: Yeah, `--whatrequires` should include everything that depends on `python`.  You just want everything that depends on `python` that you had previously installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the clones had the same packages installed before you removed python, a sure-fire way to get the list of packages needed would be to compare `rpm -qa` from each clone.

```
# on clone 1:
rpm -qa | sort > clone1.txt

# on clone 2:
rpm -qa | sort > clone2.txt
```

Get `clone1.txt` and `clone2.txt` on the same computer.  Then run

```
comm -13 clone1.txt clone2.txt
```

to see which rpms are on Clone 2 and not Clone 1.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can undo a yum command.  On the computer with python removed, try running `yum history`:

```
yum history
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
ID     | Command line             | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   284 | yum remove python        | 2014-07-09 14:47 | Remove         |  1213   
...
```

Identify the line of `yum remove python` and note the `ID`

```
yum history undo 284
```

---

However, `yum` should depend on `python` so **you may have removed `yum` as well**.  If so you'll have to download it and its dependencies manually again.  First check that your system has the needed dependencies (this list was generated on a Fedora 19 system, so double-check with your RHEL 6 clone):

```
[root@localhost ~]# repoquery -R yum
/usr/bin/python
pygpgme
pyliblzma
python >= 2.4
python(abi) = 2.7
python-iniparse
python-sqlite
python-urlgrabber >= 3.9.0-8
pyxattr
rpm >= 4.4.2
rpm-python
yum-metadata-parser >= 1.1.0
```

For each that you're missing, download the package from your RHEL 6 sources and install it manually with `rpm`.

Generally removing packages  doesn't remove all of their configuration files.  I don't know about `yum`.  Hopefully the `yum` history database is still intact after reinstalling it.

Answer (score 2):

You may have `/var/log/rpmpkgs` which has a list of all the RPM packages installed. (in RHEL 6 that list is generated by the package rpm-cron) If you have the list of packages you may look at `/var/log/yum.log` to see what packages were uninstalled.